# Running a function every 2 seconds

Tags: c#, function, timer

```
    public void InitTimer()
    {
        timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 200; // in milliseconds
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
```

Using that code from [How can I raise an event every hour (or specific time interval each hour) in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/307798/how-can-i-raise-an-event-every-hour-or-specific-time-interval-each-hour-in-ne)

I'm VERY new to C#, but I'm not sure what's wrong. I'm trying to display a messagebox in this example every 2 seconds. There are no errors, the messagebox simply does not show.

Comment: 200 milliseconds != 2 seconds.

Comment: What's the actual problem your having? Do you get an error, or does the code simply not get called?

Comment: 2 seconds would be 2000 milliseconds, not 200

Comment: Are you sure you're calling `InitTimer()`?

Comment: what if timer1_Tick function took 1 minute to finish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot to call the function in your load.

Comment: thanks, this worked, I wasn't calling the function in the load, DOH!

Comment: I wouldn't create such "sleeping functions" there are wasting resources because auf dead / sleeping threads...

Comment: Requires 15 rep, otherwise I would :P

Comment: If this is sleeping on the UI thread, it's a bad idea -- this will prevent the processing of windows messages...

Comment: @Boas Enkler You are right. It was a simple example still shouldn't have used it.

Comment: Why is this answer being downvoted?  Downvoters, explain yourselves.

Answer (score 4):

I tried out your code (changing 200ms to 2000ms), and it **did** display the message box every 2 seconds, so the problem is not the code, but more likely the way you are calling it.  I just created a sample Winforms app, and put the call to InitTimer in the form's Load event:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        InitTimer();
    }
```

When you created the project, did you create a Windows Forms application?  You should not have created a Console application, for example.

Comment: This is true, I did not call the InitTime(); Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
        Timer timer1 = new Timer();
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer1.Interval = 2000; // in miliseconds
        timer1.Start();
```

You need to put an additional Timer before timer1
this works, but make shure you init the timer

Answer (score 0):

Just set the interval of the timer to the value you need.

200 means 200 ms

so Interval = 2000 means that the code is raised every two seconds

But where is your problem ? What does not work ? 
Also there are some issues concerning ui's and non ui threads.

Comment: Set a breakpoint to the MessageBox call and see wether it is raised.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have 60 minutes in an hour, 60 seconds in a minute, and 1000 ms in a second so you can have

```
timer1.Interval = 60 * 60 * 1000; // Every hour
```

Comment: you probably misread the question, he wanted every 2 seconds, not every hour

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid locking the thread you could always spawn a new thread and continue the polling there.  Using same code you have but