# c# Function work with Timer(AutoFunction)

Tags: c#, function, automation

I do have one checking function that will run once opening the application. 
How to make it Auto Function like every 20 seconds run the function?

```
Main()
{
  Checking();
}

public void Checking() // run this function every 20 seconds
{ // some code here   
}
```

Comment: Use a timer. Set its tick to 20Sec. Claa your function in definition of timers tick event

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I raise an event every hour (or specific time interval each hour) in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307798/how-can-i-raise-an-event-every-hour-or-specific-time-interval-each-hour-in-ne)

Comment: Side note: if code is clearly not related to the question you don't need to post some random #@$@# - empty function would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the C# Timer class

```
public void Main()
{
    var myTimer = new Timer(20000);

    myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    myTimer.Enabled = true;

    Console.ReadLine();
}


private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0}", e.SignalTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Main()
{
   Timer tm = new Timer();
   tm.Interval = 20000;//Milliseconds
   tm.Tick += new EventHandler(tm_Tick);
   tm.Start();
}
void tm_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Checking();       
}

public void Checking()
{
   // Your code
}
```