# C# timer start at exact full second

Tags: c#, timer

**Is there a way to run the `Timer` so that it starts at exact full second?**

```
stateTimer = new Timer(someCallback, null, 0, 1000);
```

This one will start right away, repeating each second, but the problem is it will start exactly when I run the program which may result in `13:14:15.230` start.

I would like `13:14:15.000` start. Something like:

```
stateTimer = new Timer(someCallback, null, DateTime.Now.Date, 1000);
```

Is that possible?

**EDIT:**

After doing the console log:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")}");
```

I've noticed that 1 second interval actually gets incremented by more than one second (about 1,02 each iteration) so after 50 iterations one second is skipped. I have solved my problem by making timer run each 800ms instead. Not ideal solution, but it works, and second never gets skipped (and I have no problem in triggering the same second twice).

```
stateTimer = new Timer(someCallback, null, 0, 800);
```

Comment: Why is it a problem if the timer doesn't run exactly on the second?

Comment: You could calculate how long until the next time you would want to start it and sleep that much, then start it, but be aware that Windows is not a real-time operating system, it has no guarantee that your timer will tick at exactly the time interval you specify, only "close enough". Why do you need it to be this kind of exact?

Comment: A "second" with no fractional part is an imaginary or theoretical notion, and it's completely arbitrary.  What one person (or computer) thinks is an exact/full second, another thinks is in the middle of two seconds because it's impossible to synchronize the two.  Unless you can explain why this is necessary or useful, in your case, then this question is not of value.

Comment: Suppose that were possible and the handler starts running at exactly that time. What prevents the operating system from switching to another thread for 16 milliseconds at that moment? Nothing. So even if it were possible to do what you want, which it is not, you'd still have the same problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I raise an event every hour (or specific time interval each hour) in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307798/how-can-i-raise-an-event-every-hour-or-specific-time-interval-each-hour-in-ne)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No that is not possible. That would require you to exactly know when the CPU thinks it is a good idea to start to execute your timer code. Even if you would `Thread.Sleep` for the remaining time, it would still not mean the code is executed at the very millisecond you want to.

Instead, if you just want to do this for formatting, you can use a custom date/time format to do that.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar in a program that displayed the time and displayed the number of minutes and seconds until the user could do something.

The original code used a 1000 ms timer.  This had the problems described by the original poster.  I created a thread.  The thread had a loop:

```
private ManualResetEvent myThreadRequestExit = new ManualResetEvent(false);

while (!myThreadRequestExit.WaitOne(1000 - DateTime.UtcNow.Millisecond))
{
    // Do the one-second work here
}
```

The loop will exit and the thread will terminate when MyThreadRequestExit is set.

Although it may fire a few milliseconds after the start of the second it is close enough that the user perceives the timer as ticking when it should and it does not lose seconds as long as the work can be done in less than a second.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line before you start your timer. Sweet and simple :)

```
Thread.Sleep(1000 - DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).